# Hiding UIImageView in UICollectionViewCell when Kingfisher download fails in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, kingfisher

I want to hide my `UIImageView` in `UICollectionViewCell` and update cell size when `Kingfisher` download fails.

**My setData function called in cellForItem**

```swift
func setData(with data: Article?, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let data = data else { return }
    
    if let imageUrl = data.urlToImage, imageUrl.isValidURL, let url = URL(string: imageUrl.addingPercentEncoding) {
        self.newsImageView.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.transition(.fade(0.3))]) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                self.newsImageView.isHidden = false
            case .failure(let error):
                self.newsImageView.isHidden = true
                // the above line is not enough I should also update cell size this is the my actual problem.
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.newsImageView.isHidden = true
    }
    
}
```

`CellForItem`

```swift
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let homeCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HomeCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? HomeCollectionViewCell,
              let article = viewModel.getArticle(at: indexPath)
        
        else {
            let emptyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: EmptyArticlesCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
            return emptyCell
        }
        
        homeCell.configure(with: article, indexPath: indexPath)
        return homeCell
    }
```

`HomeCollectionViewCell.swift`

```swift
    class HomeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var homeCollectionViewCellComponent: HomeCollectionViewCellComponent!
    
.
.
.

    func configure(with data: Article, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        homeCollectionViewCellComponent.setData(with: data, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        homeCollectionViewCellComponent.prepareForReuse()
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Asteroid how can I resize my collectionview cell when image could not download

Comment: @Asteroid I know that showing image is an async operation if I call reloadItems(at: [IndexPath]) method my collectionView will be glitch a lot and the user experience will be bad. How can I approach this problem

Comment: where are you calling setData?

Comment: @Asteroid at CellForItem method.

Comment: Please add that part of your code.

Comment: @Asteroid ı have added

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `setData` call to occur directly in `cellForItemAt`. Then in the callback, you can hide the image view (like you're doing). Then immediately after that in the callback, call `collectionView.reconfigureItems(at:)` (if using iOS 15+) or `collectionView.reloadItems(at:)`

You'll likely need to implement a bool flag on the cell (or possibly the article itself) for when the image can't be loaded. Otherwise you may get into an infinite loop of reloading the cell when it reloads.

Comment: Actually, I'm calling setData in cellForItem anyway, what's the difference with what you said?

yes your right, I need to keep a flag so that when that cell reappears, the reloadItems process is not repeated.

In addition, I think if multiple images fail at the same time then reloadItems function will cause freezing issue when scrolling am I right?

Comment: @James per your code, you're not calling `setData` in `cellforItem`, you're calling it in the cell itself in the `configure` function. This will not allow you to call `reconfigureItems` or `reloadItems` in the completion handler in order to redraw the cell after hiding the image view.